# Emacs silently fails to start under Cygwin

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I installed emacs 26 under cygwin64, terminal version, no X.

When I enter emacs to start there is a second or so delay before the bash prompt reurns, the error code is set to 0.

The same thing occurs with emacs 25.

I have two machines, one Win7, the other Win10. The behaviour above is exhibited only on the Win7 machine.

I am unable to find any log info to see what might be going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: run `strace /usr/bin/emacs` it should rise a pop up with an error message. You likely had a incorrect update

Comment: You might also try running it with `-Q --debug-init` to stop it reading any startup files.

Comment: $ strace /usr/bin/emacs
strace.exe: error creating process C:\cygwin64\bin\emacs, (error 5)
$ emacs -Q --debug-init
$

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is as highlighted here.

http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Corrupt-Cygwin64-install-td130085.html

TL;DR - Problem is Trend anti virus.